# Why does Dataflow leave behind some disks after pipeline update?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

After running "update" on my pipeline, I noticed that there are newly created persistent disks that are not attached to any instances after 10+ minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ongoing known issue with the Dataflow service that causes orphaned disks during the pipeline update process.  These extra disks can be safely deleted.  The team is working on a fix.

UPDATE: The issue has now been fixed in the Dataflow service.